# How to bind the list view to joined entities instead of a single entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, listview, entity-framework-6

How to bind a property exist in a related entity in a `ListView` control :

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv_science_degree" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="scienceDegreeContainer" ItemType="DomainClasses.SCIENCEDEGREE" >

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <fieldset id="FieldSet1">

                <legend>Science Degree </legend>

                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            CODE
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            NAME
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            CATEGORY
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="jobDegreeCategoryContainer" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </fieldset>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="toappend">
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 code">
                        <%#:Item.SDEGREE_CODE%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 name">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_degree_name" Class="lbl_degree_name" runat="server" Text="<%#:Item.DEGREE_NAME.Trim()%>"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_degree_name" Class="txt_degree_name HideElement" runat="server" Text="<%#:Item.DEGREE_NAME.Trim()%>"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 cat">

                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_degree" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>

                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_degree_cat" Class="lbl_degree_cat" runat="server" Text="<%#:Item.SCATEGORY_CODE%>"></asp:Label> <%-- Want To Bind to QUALCATEGORY Entity to Bind to the Name instead of the code --%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">

                        <a id="lbtn_edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr" onclick="Edit(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                        <a id="lbtn_update" class="btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr HideElement lbtn_update" onclick="Update(this);">update</a>
                        <a id="lbtn_cancel" class="btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr HideElement lbtn_cancel" onclick="Cancel(this);">cancel</a>
                        <a id="lbtn_delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr HideElement lbtn_delete" onclick="Delete(this);">delete</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

---

Here I want to bind the list view to `QUALCATEGORY` **joined with** `SCIENCEDEGREE` so that i can bind the label `lbl_degree_cat`  the `CategoryName` property which exist in `QUALCATEGORY` entity instead of the `CategoryCode` in `SCIENCEDEGREE` entity  .

---

**EDIT:**

My Bind method :

in .cs file i call the following method in `(!IsPostBack)`

```
 protected void GetAllScienceDegrees()
        {
            using (scienceDegreeRepository repo= new scienceDegreeRepository ())
            {
               lv_science_degree.DataSource = repo.All.ToList();
               lv_science_degree.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

Comment: you need in linq to sql?

Comment: @Webruster just i need to benefit from the strongly-typed feature in the new listview + i need to use my entities (EF) not to use sql.

Comment: i need your select method , how you are binding listview

Comment: @Webruster: I edit my question, to clarify the `bind` part,Could you take a look plz.

Comment: NOTE:: `ItemType="DomainClasses.SCIENCEDEGREE"` in my listview and `repo.All.ToList()` in bind method return just a list of `SCIENCEDEGREE`

Comment: @Webruster : I edit the question , to clarify your point :)

Comment: sorry for late reply , was a busy week , what you need do is you need to create aCustomClas after joining the `QUALCATEGORY`  and `SCIENCEDEGREE` and that need to be bind to the your `ItemType=CustomClass`